# ARM64 calling conventions: caller or callee saved when there are fewer than 8 args?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm64, calling-convention, abi

This is regarding the Unix/Linux ABI for ARM 64-bit.

If one functions is using registers x0-x7 because it has received 8 parameters, and it then calls another function that also plans to use let's say x6-x7, is it expected that the caller will save those or that the callee will save them?

The Unix aarch64 ABI is unclear about this.

Comment: Every function is allowed to overwrite x0 through x7, end of story.  So if your caller has data in any of those registers that it cares about, it needs to save them before calling any other function.  But I'm not 100% sure if that's what you're asking.  The "plans to use x6-x7" is confusing because your caller has no way of knowing what the callee actually plans to use; it only knows what the ABI allows it to use.

Comment: Yes that clarifies it.

Answer (score 2):

##### The function signature doesn't affect the calling convention.

All possible arg-passing registers are always call-clobbered whether the function actually takes that many or not, so the caller should keep any "precious" values in other registers, or memory.

This is generally a good design. e.g. a function taking 2 args might want to call another function that takes more args, and wouldn't want to waste instructions saving/restoring its caller's x2 so it could use it pass an arg.

Also, with your hypothetical design, variadic functions like printf would have to restore all the arg-passing registers they might have touched, in case they were called with fewer.  (Easier to do that than to count args and only restore the ones past the end of the arg list.  Only 8 registers is only four `ldp` load-pair instructions.)

Plus, what about floating point registers?  Most functions don't take FP args, but you don't want them to waste instructions saving/restoring them if they want to internally call a math function.